# Re-usability of a used "pencil" (AA, or AAA) battery

Tags: batteries

If, when tested with my multi-meter, a used 1.5 "pencil" battery is now showing, say 1.2 V and is therefore no longer suitable for the original purpose, can it still have value for some circuit for which a 1.2 V battery would suffice or should it just be discarded? If the former, is it common to re-use such batteries, whether singly or in combination with other similarly "spent" ones? or am I missing something here?

Comment: Recycle is the keyword (not discard).

Comment: Yes, often I have taken "old" batteries from equipment that want "best" batteries and put them into torches until they do no more...

Comment: I have good results using old batteries for clocks or other devices that use very less energy. But I also am wondering if the voltage drops from 1.5 to 1.2V, is there still the same amount of 'mAh', just for 1.2V instead of 1.5?  In that case you could use it as a 'new' battery in a lower voltage-needing device.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [Joule Thief](http://www.bigclive.com/joule.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are missing something.
Depending on how you used it the battery might still have most of it's charge left or it might be almost depleted.

When a battery with a nominal voltage of 1.5 V measures 1.2 V and you just used the battery in a power hungry device (for example, a digital camera) then chances are that the battery still has a significant amount of charge left. If you leave the battery alone for an hour it will probably "recover" and measure 1.4 V or even 1.5 V.

In this case this battery might work again for a while in the high-power device. You could also use this battery in a low power device (for example: a clock or an LCD thermometer).

When a battery with a nominal voltage of 1.5 V measures 1.2 V and you didn't use the battery for a while or it is being used in a low-power device then "recovery" as mentioned above will not work. The battery has lost most of it's charge and is almost depleted. It is time to recycle it when the device stops working.

**Edit:** In case you want to learn more about this effect, watch [EEVBlog Dave's video about the Batteriser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4iEshd6izgk) where he debunks that product (on the grounds that there isn't much to gain from such a device) but while doing that he shows how the way you're discharging a battery determines how much charge you can extract.

Comment: Upvoted/Thanks ... also answered my (sub) question.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers I added a link to an EEVBlog video related to this subjcet that I think you might find interesting.

Comment: Discussion matches well with my own thoughts about it. Should help.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I checked the video. I really like the EEV videos. This one was good to follow (and with humor/sarcasm), most videos are a bit above my knowledge :-).